# Finding Histogram Mean

Tags: statistics, means, descriptive-statistics

Im trying to find the mean of the histogram below:

[image]

I found that the sum of the frequencies is $110$, so I then get that the mean should be $$\frac{19 \cdot 20 + 20 \cdot 30 + 10(21+22+23+25+26+27)}{110} = 22$$ however the mean should be between $22$ and $23$ according to the solution sheet. Any ideas on what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Use the left bin endpoints to calculate a lower bound on the mean and the right endpoints to calculate an upper bound. Beyond that it is not clear where the mean should be between these bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *midpoint* of each bar, not the left of each bar. In other words, use $19.5$ rather than $19$; use $20.5$ rather than $20$, etc. Note that this makes sense because the histogram says that there are $20$ observations *between* $19$ and $20$, so we assume these observations are evenly distributed throughout the class $19 < x < 20$, and so the *average* of these $20$ observations is $19.5.$

Also, take note that we *assume these observations are evenly distributed throughout the class*, which is an assumption, i.e. it may be false. But this is what me must do with grouped data: we must make assumptions in order to calculate any statistics (e.g. the mean or interquartile range) from the data.